# How to find the appropriate rotation of a pentagon for fitting into a LibGDX hex-tessellated sphere?

Tags: vector, libgdx, geometry, transform

I've got a tricky question today which involves a lot of vectors. I'm trying to keep them all straight. What I have is this shape (mostly hexagons with 12 pentagons): https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCPWF.jpg

And I want to place 12 pentagon meshes into their 12 spots. I start by creating the 12 meshes at the origin (the center of this shape) and then using the following code to rotate and move them into position.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
          Vector3 pentPoint = pentPoints.get(i); // The center of each pentagon.
          ModelInstance pent = pents.get(i);

          Vector3 direction = (pentPoint).cpy().sub(new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
                .nor();
          direction.set(direction.x, direction.y, direction.z);
          pent.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Y, direction);
          pent.transform.setTranslation(pentPoint);}
```

Now, this is almost what I need. It results in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4OpO.jpg. Forgetting about the scaling for now, you can see that the pentagon is rotated improperly. It doesn't line up with its slot. I know that I can fix this rotation using `pent.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y, *value*);` based on some *value* for each pentagon. The problem is, I have no idea how I can calculate what this value should be.

Can anyone help or point me to some resources? Alternatively, I could use the fact that I know the coordinate of every vertex in the shape to fill in these pentagons by drawing triangles using LibGDX's ModelBuilder. I think this would be less performant than positioning the .objs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about the library you're using, but maybe I can help with the geometry. One approach would be to draw a mesh for 1/5 of one of the pentagons. I suggest you do that in place, rather than at the origin. You need to know two adjacent vertices of a pentagon. From that, you can easily calculate the center of the pentagon (I can supply formulas if you wish). The three points you now have determine a triangle which is a "fundamental domain" for the rotation group of the dodecahedron. If you have a mesh on the fundamental domain, it can be propagated to the other 4/5 of the pentagon you chose by repeating a 72 degree rotation about the axis through the origin determined by the center of the pentagon. Call that rotation A. You can represent it by axis angle, quaternion, whatever.

To propagate the mesh to other pentagons in the figure, you just need one more rotation: a 180 degree rotation which takes your chosen pentagon to another nearby pentagon. Again, I could give a formula for the axis if you like, but if you can find the center of a second pentagon with the information you already have, the axis is determined by the midpoint of the segment connecting the two centers. (You may have to normalize the point determining the axis, depending on how you represent rotations.) Call the 180 degree rotation about that axis rotation B.

Rotation A and B together generate the entire 60 element rotation group of the icosahedron, which will allow you to propagate the mesh on the fundamental domain to every other pentagon in the figure. If you're not careful, however, you may hit some parts twice and others not at all. I think you can do it in this order: start with a fundamental domain. 4 A's fill in the first pentagonal face (let's call it the north pole). Then a B will map that pentagon to an adjacent pentagon. 4 more A's will fill in a meridian of pentagons. Another B will take a pentagon on the meridian to the other meridian. 4 more A's will fill in the second meridian. Finally another B will map a pentagon on the second meridian to the south pole.

The orientations of all the pentagons will be correct in this procedure.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for this, that does help! It's definitely a super-clear description of how to get the results I'm after. I'll have to give it a shot tonight. I'm just wondering, since this effectively uses 5 triangle meshes for each pentagon, I could probably get the exact same result without any of the rotation math just by having code render the triangles from the vertices I know belong to pentagons. I'll need to do a bit more digging on LibGDX performance to find out if using the meshes actually matters any.

Comment: Oh, I just thought of another little detail. It's possible to find a Hamiltonian cycle of the faces of a dodecahedron: see the rightmost graphs in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html (faces of the dodecahedron correspond to vertices of the icosahedron). Each of the edges on that graph correspond to some combination of A and B rotations; say the first edge is B, the second edge is A, the third edge is AAB, and so on, which gives a sequence of rotations that will cover the dodecahedron in 12 moves (once you have computed the rotations). Not really important but it's kind of neat.

Comment: That is neat! I've decided to try implementing this solution now. I'm running into a bit of confusion regarding, "the axis is determined by the midpoint of the segment connecting the two centers." I've got my midpoint, but how do I make an axis with it? Which way does this axis run through this point?

Comment: In a mathematical sense, the axis is determined by the origin and the midpoint. However, I think most ways of specifying rotations required a normalized point for the axis rather than any old point. So you should "normalize" the point by dividing by its norm (length). I.e., if the midpoint is `(m.x,m.y,m.z)`, the normalized point is `(m.x/N,m.y/N,m.z/N)` where `N=sqrt(m.x^2+m.y^2+m.z^2)`. Once you have the normalized point you can represent the rotation as a quaternion, axis/angle, or whatever. The same for the rotation about the center of the pentagon.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got that. Problem is, it looks like I'm rotating around that point the wrong way. For example, the pentagon is swinging 180 degrees around that point as if it were the center of a carousel, but it looks like I need to swing the pentagon 180 degrees up and over the point as if it were a catapult. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I think carousel is right, catapult is wrong ... catapult will change the orientation of the figure. If you do want a catapult, you would need another axis perpendicular to the axis you found and also perpendicular to the segment connecting the centers of the pentagons; you could find the axis by cross-product. Then you would need to translate to the origin, perform the rotation, and translate back. I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.

Comment: You were right. I was screwing up the rotation when I went to project the shapes onto the surface of the sphere. This is what I managed to pull off thanks to your help: http://i.imgur.com/nLTAh6U.jpg. Now I just need to figure out how to fill in the hexagons...

Comment: The hexagons look the same, but I suspect they're of different types (when projected to the sphere). What I suggest as a straightforward way forward is to consider the fundamental domain I mentioned in my answer, only enlarge it beyond the pentagon. Imagine lines (great circles, actually) originating at the centers of the pentagons and passing through the vertices until they hit other lines from other pentagons. The result will be lines splitting the sphere into 60 pieces, fundamental domains. Pick one of the fundamental domains. It will have 1/5 of a pentagon, a number of whole hexagons ...

Comment: and parts of other hexagons. In your picture it will be a big triangle with top vertex in the center of the top pentagon and bottom edge on the line right between two pentagons. Each hexagon inside the fundamental domain can be moved around the sphere by exactly the same group of rotations which moves the pentagons. Hexagons which cross the boundary are more problematic ... maybe only replicate them if they cross the left boundary or left half of the bottom boundary. Or subdivide the hexagons into triangles before you replicate.